# SourceTree installation is failed

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I downloaded SourceTreeSetup.exe file from the SourceTree site.
 - version: SourceTreeSetup-1.10.23.1.exe

I installed it in my Windows 7 (32bit), and can find the Icon in my desktop.

When I run the SourceTree, a error popup is shown.

> Downloading from https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/PortableGcmSt-1.8.1.6.7z ...

with Below error popup.

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed. Send has encountered an unexpected error.
>
> System.IO.IOException: The transport connection could not read data from the current connection that was forcibly disconnected by the remote host.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The current connection was forcibly disconnected by the remote host

I suspect our company's firewall, but I don't know exactly.
I tried to googling with these error, but I cannot find any clue.

Anyone to help, please?

Comment: Have you got Git installed on your machine. SourceTree kind of work with extension to git giving a UI based version controlling rather than command-line. If that doesn't work you can use [Gitkraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/)

Comment: It took me quite a time to fix. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556235/4190858) helped in my case

Comment: It took me quite a time to fix this. In my case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556235/4190858) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can add proxy setting in user.config for the Source Tree.

File Path:

`C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_<ramdom strings>\<version no>`

Add the following settings.

```
<setting name="ProxyServerMode" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Custom</value>
</setting>
<setting name="ProxyServer" serializeAs="String">
    <value>your proxy server address</value>
</setting>
<setting name="ProxyPort" serializeAs="String">
    <value>your proxy port#</value>
</setting>
```

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/Installing-SourceTree-1-10-in-an-offline-environment/qaq-p/386124

Answer (score 1):

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6886

the solution for me was to download this version: 
https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/ga/SourceTreeSetup-1.10.24.1.exe