# Installing Docker Desktop 4.5.0 failed: Componet.CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed: Not found

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Windows 10, Version 2004 (OS build 19041.1415)
I am trying to install docker desktop 4.5.0 after having installed WSL2 for Ubuntu. I tried repeatedly after a fresh reboot but this problem doesnt go away. Can anyone shed some light?

```
Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed: Not found 
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

Full log:

```
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Edition: Enterprise
Id: 2004
Build: 19041
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\Users\naus-ad-xxx\AppData\Local\Docker\install-log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer(1).exe" "install" -package "res:DockerDesktop" --relaunch-as-admin
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[11:23:53.421][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader][Info   ] No install path specified, looking for default installation registry key
[11:23:53.421][Program           ][Info   ] No installation found
[11:23:53.784][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Cancel pending background download
[11:23:53.822][BackgroundTransfer][Info   ] Cancel current background transfer job
[11:23:54.856][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Using package: res:DockerDesktop
[11:23:54.856][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Downloading
[11:23:57.240][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Extracting manifest
Failed to track the installer started event[11:23:57.643][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Manifest found: version=74594, displayVersion=4.5.0, channelUrl=https://desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/appcast.xml
[11:23:57.643][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Checking prerequisites
[11:23:57.666][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Prompting for optional features
[11:23:59.863][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Unpacking artifacts
[11:26:07.556][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[11:26:10.120][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[11:26:10.130][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction
**[11:26:10.181][InstallWorkflow   ][Error  ] Installation failed
Exception type: System.Exception, Exception message: Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed: Not found , StackTrace:
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()**
[11:26:10.185][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[11:26:10.186][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[11:26:10.186][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.UnpackArtifactsStep
[11:26:10.194][FileSystem        ][Info   ] Deleting C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
[11:26:10.761][FileSystem        ][Info   ] Deleted C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker successfully
[11:26:10.761][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ExtractManifestStep
[11:26:10.764][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.DownloadStep
```

Comment: if i uncheck "install required components for wsl" then installation will succeed. What copmonetns are required? I have manually installed wsl2 on the machine already and i have a ubuntu distribution running.

Answer (score 28):

In my case the problem was with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)

Running this command in cmd as Administrator fixed the problem :

```
CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s
```

I have got this command from this [article](https://www.virtuallyboring.com/microsoft-wmi-invalid-class-error-0x80041010/)

Comment: Windows > "cmd" > Run as administrator. 
Then, I had to break this into three commands: 
1. `cd C:\Windows\System32\webem`
2. `dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt`
3. `for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s`

Rebooted, and then I ran the DockerDesktop installer successfully!

Comment: This solution worked seamlessly for Docker Version : 4.6.1 on Windows.
Windows Version: 10 Enterprise 21H2 (Installed with WSL2)

Comment: Worked for me. I'm using version 4.16.3

Comment: Worked for me on Docker Desktop 4.16.3, Windows 11

Comment: Thanks.. Worked for me on Windows 10 Pro and Docker Version 4.19.0

Comment: you are a wizard or whoever found this solution

Comment: this solution also worked for v 4.21.1

Comment: This fails for me on version 4.22.0 with the same error message, even after a reboot.

Comment: this solution worked for 4.22.1

Comment: You are a Wizard Harry! I have been trying to solve this for 5 days, worked like a charm in 4.23.0!

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I had similar issue with 4.9.0 and tried installing 4.0.0 still my problem did not resolve. I removed trace from c drive (C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop, C:\Program Files\Docker) and tried installing again but no luck. Later i found forum discussing about this. (https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1857) repeated the steps in windows command prompt running as admin.

1. sc config winmgmt start=disabled
2. net stop winmgmt
3. Winmgmt /salvagerepository %windir%\System32\wbem
4. Winmgmt /resetrepository %windir%\System32\wbem
5. sc config winmgmt start=auto
6. Get-NetIPInterface

This steps helped me to install docker 4.9.0

Comment: Hey Ramesh, i get this error when running the first command :)  positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'start=disabled'.
At line:1 char:1
+ sc config winmgmt start=disabled

Comment: same here... You need to use the Command Prompt in Admin mode and it will work.

Comment: On Windows 10 Home and these steps worked for me to install Docker Desktop 4.12.0, thank you!  One small note (though people may be able to figure it out), but step 6 is a Powershell command and didn't work in CMD.

Comment: thank you. works on my windows 10 laptop. 

Comment: If you get an error about a positional argument, try using `sc.exe` instead of `sc`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check WMI: https://www.virtuallyboring.com/microsoft-wmi-invalid-class-error-0x80041010/
If failed to initialize all classes, check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/684166/failed-to-initialize-all-required-wmi-classes.html and run the commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: commands on the microsoft link solved my problem, even though not all commands worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when attempting to install 4.12.0. I tried all sorts of things and the only one that worked for me was running the batch file (as Administrator) listed in the following post: https://programmersought.com/article/29075200559/

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too, when installing the latest version 4.5.0 (It had been released on Feb 10th, 2022) Try to downgrade to version 4.4.4 it worked for me.

You can find the released note and older versions on this [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/)

Note: You can install an older version and update to latest version 4.5.0

Comment: No juice for me ;( I tried to install 4.4.4 and 4.4.3, both having same problem... man, wish i could use a mac!

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was starting this service:

Windows Installer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Exactly this one actually helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
sc config winmgmt start=disabled
net stop winmgmt
Winmgmt /salvagerepository %windir%\System32\wbem
Winmgmt /resetrepository %windir%\System32\wbem
sc config winmgmt start=auto
Get-NetIPInterface
```

following this command in cmd running as a admin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running installer in Admin Powershell

```
Start-Process 'Docker Desktop Installer.exe' -Wait install
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 Pro, Docker Version 4.27.1 
I solved my issue by following these steps.

1. Run Windows command prompt as Administrator.
2. Go to this directory -> **CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM**
3. the run ->  **dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt**
4. at last run this -> **for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s**

Reboot your Windows computer the run the docker installer again.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following worked for me like a charm.

CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s

Thank you for providing such a great solution as I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add "Thank you" answers. An answer here should be a unique attempt to answer the question, not a confirmation that another answer worked for you. As you gain additional reputation, you'll earn new [privileges](/privileges) and will be able to upvote the answer or even reward the answer with a bounty. These are the SO ways of saying, *"Thanks!"* You can gain reputation (and resulting privileges) by asking well-received questions, posting helpful answers, and even by making helpful edits to existing questions and answers.